# Using switch in a device to indicate water level of two different tanks

Tags: mosfet, resistors, sensor, switches, diodes

Following Device (circuit) to indicate the water level of two different tanks.

`N MOSFET` is used as sensor and 5 LEDs as output to indicate water levels.

Switches S1,S2,S3,S4,S5 are coming form tank one; and S6,S7,S8,S9,S10 are coming form tank two.

Separator S11 is used to switch between tank 1 and tank 2.

[image]

I think Separator is not enough to switch between two tanks which produces Mix/Misleading results.

I can not figure out, how to isolate both tank's output using Separator and diodes. I can understand there must be diodes to block current flow kindly help..

**Update:**
added 2 diodes between S1 and R1, and also between S6 and R1. still did not get what it suppose to do.

[image]

Comment: Did you think that D6 wouldn't conduct?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams D6 suppose to block the current flow. Fact is I don't understand where to place this diode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete D6, and add diodes (pointing down) between EACH switch and its associated FET gate and pull-down resistor.

Comment: Did you mean first diode should be in between S1 and R1?

Comment: Yes, you need a diode between S1 and R1, and also between S6 and R1 - repeat for each LED.

Comment: Where do you get "5 diodes in series"? You want one diode in series with each switch.

Comment: updated circuit is added to question kindly take a look.

Comment: You should remove the wire at the top right, where D6 was in your original drawing - that wire shorts S11.  You need to add pairs of diodes like D6 and D7 in each "channel".

Comment: the same result can be produce with micro controller? can you suggest any for that purpose